# when I am using bxslider with lightbox plus jquery...bxslider not working

Tags: bxslider, lightbox2

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).bxSlider is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (?<sdre:415)
    at k (lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js?ver=1.2111:sourcemap:24)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js?ver=1.2111:sourcemap:24)
    at Function.ready (lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js?ver=1.2111:sourcemap:24)
    at HTMLDocument.g (lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js?ver=1.2111:sourcemap:14)
```

Comment: * Lightbox v2.9.0
 * by Lokesh Dhakar
 *
 * More info:
 * http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/
 *
 * Copyright 2007, 2015 Lokesh Dhakar
 * Released under the MIT license
 * https://github.com/lokesh/lightbox2/blob/master/LICENSE
 */

Comment: * Sizzle CSS Selector Engine v2.2.0-pre
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2008, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2014-12-16
 */

Comment: /*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.4
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Includes Sizzle.js
 * http://sizzlejs.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. and other contributors
 * Released under the MIT license
 * http://jquery.org/license
 *
 * Date: 2015-04-28T16:01Z
 */